# Suppress Error in Suppression file gives error : The Selected Message Could not be suppressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, fxcop

[image]

I am Using Visual Studio 2015, FxCop 14.0. with Custom rules, and trying to suppress message in **GlobalSuppressions.cs**. I have set path of the Global Suppression in Project file 
`<PropertyGroup ..>
..
..
<CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>$(SolutionDir)\xxx\xx\xxx\GlobalSuppressions.cs</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
</PropertyGroup>`

can anyone please help me fix this.

Comment: And WHICH message do you try to suppress?

Comment: @BernhardHiller: Custom Rule error as well as pre-defined Analysis errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done following steps and problem get resolved :

1. Delete the existing `GlobalSuppression.cs` file from project.
2. Clean Solution and rebuild.
3. Now try to suppress the errors. This will create new file and will suppress all warnings.

Answer (score 4):

This means that there is already a GlobalSuppressions.cs file present, but it is not included in the project.

To resolve this, enable "Show All Files" in the solution explorer, right-click the GlobalSuppressions.cs file which should now appear, and "Include In Project".

Comment: This was the solution for me. The correct answer should be this as it is a better way then what Avinash suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this...

The above answers did not work for me. So give them a try first but if that doesn't work here's what did it for me:

1. Delete all `GlobalSuppressions.cs` files from the project
2. Clean the solution.
3. Select `Analyze` > `Configure Code Analysis` > `For Solution`
4. Find the project with troubles and select `Reset`
5. Run Code Analysis and everything should be good